# has_one Dynamically Generated Accessors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, has-one

When a `has_many` relationship is declared on a model, an accessor method is added dynamically, allowing an array of ids to be passed in:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :foos
end
```

Which allows:

```
$ m = Example.create!
$ m.foo_ids = [1, 2, 3]
```

However when a `has_one` relationship is declared, so such accessor is created:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :foo
end
```

Which doesn't allow:

```
$ m = Example.create!
$ m.foo_id = 1 # No method error
```

**Why is there this discrepancy?**

Why is it possible to set multiple associations from a form using their ids, but to set a singular association, a nested form is needed and an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` needs to be defined on the model? This feels like a discrepancy in the API.

Answer (score 1):

For has_one you should use single instead of plural:

```
has_one :foo
```

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo in my example (now fixed). The question remains. Why doesn't rails generate a `foo_id` accessor?

Comment: Then just use `m.foo.id`

Comment: The reason of discrepancy is that in case of `has_many` you need to iterate over objects, so method `_ids` is generated for this purpose by ActiveRecord. In case of `has_one` you don't need it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm interested in *why*. This is particularly of interest in nested forms. I can set `foo_ids` without worrying about nesting, but with a `has_one` relationship I need to do things differently and use a nested form along with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because virtually none of association macros create `"{{association_name}}_id"` accessor - it's created by `ActiveRecord` on the basis of columns in DB table. Besides, `has_one` association means that the associated model has foreign key column, so if your associations agree with DB schema, this should not raise error:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.example_id
```

Comment: This is true, but in a `has_many` relationship, the situation is the same: it is the many that contain the foreign key, not the model that declares the `has_many`, yet `ActiveRecord` generates a `foo_ids` accessor.

Comment: @Pedr I think this foo_id accessor is not generated because it could interfere with already existing accessor generated from DB column. Also, I think it could be misleading - it could generate assumption that this is foreign key.

Comment: But the generated accessor will be on the `belongs_to` model. The model that `has_many` doesn't have a `foo_id` column or accessor.

Comment: @Pedr It may not be true if you want to build 'self' association.

Comment: This is true. I hadn't considered that. So perhaps that explains why it isn't named `foo_id`, but still seems strange to treat a singular resource differently for a multiple resource when it comes to nested forms.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), `collection_singular_ids=` (m.foo_ids=) method makes the collection contain only the objects identified by the supplied primary key values, by adding and deleting as appropriate. That means it will assign the foos with ids [1, 2, 3] to the example m.

Now they have a different method `collection=objects` (m.foo=) that will receive the array of foo objects as parameter and will associate those foos to example.

Finally, when we are using `has_one` association there can be only one object associated with the example. so we don't need two different methods for the same work, hence they don't have `collection_singular_id=` method as it will be confusing but they have `association=(associate)` method to assign the association.

From the guide:

> The association= method assigns an associated object to this object. Behind the scenes, this means extracting the primary key from this object and setting the associate object's foreign key to the same value.

Comment: You say 'we don't need two different methods for the same work', but these two methods would be different and that is the whole point of my question. Directly setting a singular association as it stands involves passing an instance of the model into the method. A method like example_id would allow an insntance to be by set *by passing an id*. This would make it much easier to set a singular association from a form without using nested forms and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: yes.. I agree on that point. I am not sure why they don't have that method but we can achieve what you want here by creating a method in the model and adding that to after_save.

Answer (score 0):

Why should that accessor be created for a single instance? There is no need to pass an array of IDs to it. The accessor `foo_id=` would be equivalent to `foo.id=`, so why create it?

Comment: Because if it was created, you wouldn't need to nest a form in a situation where you wanted to set `a has_one` relationship.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Well, since `has_many` creates an ActiveRecord collection object there are several methods that come with it (including those accessors). However, `has_one` only associates one model with another without creating any new methods for these models other than `create_foo` etc. If you want the `foo_id` accessor you have to define it in the 'Example'-Model yourself.

Answer (score -2):

For dynamically generated acessors you should use method_missing in your model.

For having dynamic associated model use polimirphic association.